# Assert SpringSecurity encoded password in test

Tags: grails, spring-security, encode

I want to do something like:

```
class MySpec extends Specification{
    def 'test'(){
        given: 'a user that has its password encoded by SpringSecurity'
            def user = new SecUser(username: 'blah', password: 'p').save(flush:true)
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance('MD5')
            md.update('p'.getBytes('UTF-8'))
        expect: 'the password should be encoded with MD5 algorithm'
            user.password == (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(md.digest())
    }
}
```

In my Config.groovy I added the following line:

grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm="MD5"

This is not working (the assertion fails). Any Ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the encoding yourself, try using

```
springSecurityService.encodePassword(user.password)
```

Don't forget your salt! If you have one (and you should consider one if you don't!) you can pass that in as the second argument.

Comment: I can't get springSecurityService injected in my Spec and if i initialize 'new SpringSecurityService()', its dependencies aren't injected. Any suggestion?